# How to Generate URL for php link

Tags: c#

This is SMS sender web site and I want to make a C# function for this. At firs I want to generate link. For example I tried : http://www.magtifun.ge/index.php?page=11&lang=en&act=1&user=mamasha&password=7504a and it does not work.

Down here is a code from that site's Inspect Element

```
<!--

 Start user Action Form 

-->
<form action="index.php?page=11&lang=en" method="post" name="user_action">
    <!--

     Form Header 

    -->
    <div class="tbl_header">

        Log In

    </div>
    <!--

     Action 

    -->
    <input id="act" type="hidden" value="1" name="act"></input>
    <!--

     User 

    -->
    <p class="space_top"></p>
    <p>
        <input id="user" class="round_border medium_box" type="text" name="user"></input>
    </p>
    <!--

     Password 

    -->
    <p></p>
    <p>
        <input id="password" class="round_border medium_box" type="password" name="password"></input>
    </p>
```

> I wanted to do this but it does not work. Is it right way?

```
  {
     string URL = "http://www.magtifun.ge/index.php?page=11&lang=ge";
                WebClient webClient = new 

WebClient();
        NameValueCollection formData = new NameValueCollection();
        formData["act"] = "1";
        formData["user"] = "mamasha";
        formData["password"] = "75045a";

        byte[] responseBytes = webClient.UploadValues(URL, "POST", formData);
        string responsefromserver = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(responseBytes);
        Console.WriteLine(responsefromserver);
        webClient.Dispose();

        Thread.Sleep(5);
        send("591931123", "Hello vaxo");

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
    public static void send(string n, string t){
        ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
        string postDate = "recipient=" + n;
        postDate +="&message_body=" + t;
        byte[] date = encoding.GetBytes(postDate);
        WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create("http://www.magtifun.ge/scripts/sms_send.php");
        req.Method = "POST";
        req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        req.ContentLength = date.Length;

        Stream stream = req.GetRequestStream();
        stream.Write(date, 0, date.Length);
        stream.Close();

        WebResponse respons = req.GetResponse();
        stream = respons.GetResponseStream();

        StreamReader st = new StreamReader(stream);
        Console.WriteLine(st.ReadToEnd());
        st.Close();
        stream.Close();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What is the relation to c#?

Comment: What did you try ? Show us the C# code!

Comment: what you mean _it does not work_? any error or what?

Comment: You can see it now that what I wanted to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must perform POST request to the http://www.magtifun.ge/index.php page. I assume it will not work without cookies, because that site requires authorization.